# A new generalization of Bottema's theorem

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

Is the  proof given below acceptable?

> **Claim**. In any triangle $\triangle ABC$ construct isosceles triangles $\triangle ACE$ and $\triangle BDC$ on sides $AC$ and $BC$ , with apices at points $A$ and $B$ , such that $\angle EAC+\angle CBD=180^{\circ}$ holds true. Let points $F$ and $G$ divide legs $AE$ and $BD$ respectively in the same arbitrary ratio . The midpoint $H$ of the line segment that connects points $F$ and $G$ is independent of the location of $C$ .

[image]

GeoGebra applet that demonstrates this claim can be found [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/xuyvagyy).

The following proof is inspired by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3842030/15660) to my previous question.

**Proof**. Consider $A$, $B$ , $C$ as complex numbers and choose a $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Denote $\angle EAC=\alpha$ and $\angle CBD=\beta$ . Then,
$$F=A+\lambda(E-A)=A+\lambda(\cos \alpha +i \sin \alpha)(C-A)$$
$$G=B+\lambda(D-B)=B+\lambda(\cos (-\beta) +i \sin (-\beta))(C-B)$$
$$H=\frac{1}{2}(F+G)=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(A+\lambda(\cos \alpha +i \sin \alpha)(C-A)+B+\lambda(-\cos \alpha -i \sin \alpha)(C-B))=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(A+\lambda(\cos \alpha + i\sin \alpha)C-\lambda(\cos \alpha + i\sin \alpha)A+ $$$$B-\lambda(\cos \alpha + i\sin \alpha)C+\lambda(\cos \alpha + i\sin \alpha)B)=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(A(1-\lambda(\cos \alpha + i\sin \alpha))+B(1+\lambda(\cos \alpha + i\sin \alpha)))$$

This shows that $H$ is independent of the location of $C$.

Q.E.D.

**EDIT**

It is possible to generalize this claim even further.

> **Claim**.In any triangle $\triangle ABC$ construct triangles $\triangle ACE$ and $\triangle BDC$ on sides $AC$ and $BC$  such that $\frac{AE}{AC}=\frac{BD}{BC}$ and $\angle EAC+\angle CBD=180^{\circ}$ hold true. Let points $F$ and $G$ divide sides $AE$ and $BD$ respectively in the same arbitrary ratio . The midpoint $H$ of the line segment that connects points $F$ and $G$ is independent of the location of $C$ .

[image]

GeoGebra applet that demonstrates this claim can be found [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/aj8zwk8e).

**Proof**. Consider $A$, $B$ , $C$ as complex numbers and choose a $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Denote $\angle EAC=\alpha$ , $\angle CBD=\beta$ and $\frac{AE}{AC}=\frac{BD}{BC}=k$ . Then,
$$F=A+\lambda(E-A)=A+\lambda \cdot k(\cos \alpha +i \sin \alpha)(C-A)$$
$$G=B+\lambda(D-B)=B+\lambda \cdot k(\cos (-\beta) +i \sin (-\beta))(C-B)$$
$$H=\frac{1}{2}(F+G)=\frac{1}{2}(A+\lambda \cdot k(\cos \alpha +i \sin \alpha)(C-A)+$$$$B+\lambda \cdot k(-\cos \alpha -i \sin \alpha)(C-B))=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(A+\lambda \cdot k(\cos \alpha + i\sin \alpha)C-\lambda \cdot k(\cos \alpha + i\sin \alpha)A+$$$$B-\lambda \cdot k(\cos \alpha + i\sin \alpha)C+\lambda \cdot k(\cos \alpha + i\sin \alpha)B)=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(A(1-\lambda \cdot k(\cos \alpha + i\sin \alpha))+B(1+\lambda \cdot k(\cos \alpha + i\sin \alpha)))$$
This shows that $H$ is independent of the location of $C$.

Q.E.D.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3841979/91708) also seems to generalize pretty well.

Comment: A [geogebra demo](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/eht5kwam) for the generalization.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to see this is with spiral similarities.  We’ll use the fact that spiral similarities [come in pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_similarity#Pairs_of_spiral_similarities).

[image: diagram]

Reflect $C$ over $A$ to $I$.  Since $IAF \sim CBG$, there’s a spiral similarity $OIAF \sim OCBG$ with some center $O$.  $OIF \sim OCG$ pairs with $OIC \sim OFG$, which extends to $OIAC \sim OFHG$ using the midpoints of $IC$ and $FG$.  Then $OIA \sim OFH$ pairs with $OIF \sim OAH$, while $OIA \sim OCB$ pairs with $OIC \sim OAB$.  These combine to $OICF \sim OABH$.  Thus the angles of $\triangle ABH$ equal the angles of $\triangle ICF$, which are independent of the position of $C$ because the ratios $AI : AC : AF$ and angles $∠IAC, ∠CAF$ are fixed.